# How to know which version of Microsoft Office a particular Add-in project targets?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsto

If I have a VSTO project open in Visual Studio, how do I know which version of MS Office it targets?

Is it possible to change or broaden the scope of versions of MS Office that the project targets?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no place in the project that explicitly says something like "Office 2010", I think you just have to look at the references. 14 means 2010, 15 is 2013, and 16 is 2016 iirc. You can swap out references to change the target version, by picking them from a different directory.